# How would I go about in making a letter swapper in batch?

Tags: batch-file

I am trying to make a secret code thingy but my code just crashes and I know its because its ridiculously long but I don't know how to make it easier to edit or simpler. could someone help? I am just repeating the same bit of code for every letter in a string.

so the code below would be repeated 25 times to detect every letter in a string in my code currently.

```
CODE:
if %c1% equ a set d1=`
if %c1% equ b set d1=~
if %c1% equ c set d1=!
if %c1% equ d set d1=@
if %c1% equ e set d1=#
if %c1% equ f set d1=$
if %c1% equ g set d1=%
if %c1% equ h set d1=^
if %c1% equ i set d1=&
if %c1% equ j set d1=*
if %c1% equ k set d1=(
if %c1% equ l set d1=)
if %c1% equ m set d1=-
if %c1% equ n set d1=_
if %c1% equ o set d1=+
if %c1% equ p set d1=\
if %c1% equ q set d1=|
if %c1% equ r set d1=]
if %c1% equ s set d1=[
if %c1% equ t set d1={
if %c1% equ u set d1=}
if %c1% equ v set d1="
if %c1% equ w set d1='
if %c1% equ x set d1=:
if %c1% equ y set d1=;
if %c1% equ z set d1=<--------------
```

Comment: The correct way to define a variable with a string value is `Set "Var=Value"`, and the correct way to compare a variable value with a string is `If "%Var%" == "String"`. Put those two togerther, and you'd have, for example: `If "%c1%" == "t" Set "d1={"`.

Answer (score 0):

A simpler approach is to use a vbs script within your batch:

```bat
@ECHO OFF

:# Example usage of encrypt function

 Set /P "input=Enter input: "

 Call :encrypt input outfile.dat "+ 117"
 Set input

 Call :encrypt input outfile.dat "- 117" /D
 Set input

Goto :Eof

:encrypt <VarName> <Outfile.ext> <Key Offset> <Optional: /D>
:# /D Switch specifies Decrypt mode
:# Key offset: "+|- 1 ~ 138"

 Setlocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion
 Set "Params=%*"

 Set "Data.Encrypt="
 Set "Data.Outfile=%~2"
 Set "Encrypt.Key=%~3"

 If "!Params:/D=!" == "!Params!" (
  Set "Data.Encrypt=!%~1!"
 )Else (
  <"!Data.Outfile!" (
   Set /p "Data.Encrypt="
  )
 )

 (
  ECHO Dim objFSO 'File System Object
  ECHO Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject"^)
  ECHO Dim objTS 'Text Stream Object
  ECHO Const ForWriting = 2
  ECHO Set objTS = objFSO.OpenTextFile("!Data.Outfile!", ForWriting, True^)
  ECHO objTS.Write(encode("!Data.Encrypt!"^)^)
  ECHO wscript.sleep "1000"
  ECHO function encode(s^)
  ECHO For i = 1 To Len(s^)
  ECHO newtxt = Mid( s, i, 1^)
  ECHO newtxt = Chr(Asc(newtxt^) !Encrypt.Key!^)
  ECHO coded = coded + (newtxt^)
  ECHO Next
  ECHO encode = coded
  ECHO End function
  ECHO objTS.Close(^)
  ECHO Set bjFSO = Nothing 'Destroy the object.
  ECHO Set objTS = Nothing 'Destroy the object.
 ) >"%TEMP%\%~n0_encrypter.vbs"

 START "" /wait "%TEMP%\%~n0_encrypter.vbs"

 DEL /Q "%TEMP%\%~n0_encrypter.vbs"

 <"!Data.Outfile!" (
  Endlocal & Set /p "%~1="
 )

GOTO :EOF
```